# Can't execute ISETool.exe from the command prompt (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to use the Isolated Storage Explorer tool from Windows Phone SDK in order to retrieve data stored in specific Windows Phone Apps' IsolatedStorage and copy it to a folder that resides in my computer.

My computer runs Windows 8 Pro, and i have both the WP7 and WP8 SDKs installed.

The problem is that when i run the command prompt and insert a command line (such as the one below) i get an error that states:

"This app can't run on your PC"

How do i solve this? Thanks

Example:

> ISETool.exe ts xd f8ce6878-0aeb-497f-bcf4-65be961d4bba c:\data\myfiles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you try using the [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) instead of what you are doing there. It will give you a nice UI to work with instead of trying to get a command line tool to work.

If you really want to use that tool then please post which directory you are running it from otherwise it is hard to tell why it won't work.